# Tag mismatch (or rather "technical glitch")

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Looks like there's a little glitch in our tags:

[image: tag or synonym?]

IMHO there should be ***either*** a tag ***or*** a synonym named "reset", but never both. The screenshot is from the "edit tags" dialog. If I select  the left red-box, it adds "factory-reset" (as expected). Selecting the right one in fact adds "reset". Calling https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset gets redirected to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset.

Could this be left-overs from some incomplete merge? How to get it cleaned up?

Comment: Not a bug - this behavior is intended to give folks a chance to review synonyms before an (irreversible) merge is performed. Moderators can merge once this is done.

Comment: Didn't know that non-moderators could merge synonyms as well -- looks like I've missed an option somewhere? If anyone other than mods, certainly a 20k+ (me) should then be able to?

Comment: Not merge, but create: http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Comment: Ah, now I've got it -- thanks, that Penny took a while to sink #D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this does appear to have been a case where two tags were synonymized but not merged, thereby leaving behind [reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset) on the questions that had it at the time the synonym was created.

I've retagged all such questions, so it should no longer appear in the list as anything other than a synonym of [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset).

Comment: A quick-check proves you were successful -- thanks! :) (hm, I could have re-tagged them myself, I just wasn't sure if that would remove "helpful information" in case a deeper investigation might take place for a failed merge or the like)